# If folder with todays date exists script - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to run some `AD Audits` and I'm having a hard time with creating a folder in `Powershell` with today's date.

This is what I'm trying to do.

If folder ADAudit\**TodaysDate**  doesn't exist then create "ADAudit\**TodaysDate**" then run a `Get-QADUser` script.  The `ADAudit` folder should live in the users document folder.

This is what I have so far.

```
$check = Test-Path -PathType Container 'ADAudit\$((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))'
if($check -eq $false){
New-Item 'ADAudit\$((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))' -type Directory
}
Get-QADUser **QADUser Query Here**
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$audit_folder_name = 'ADAudit' + (Get-Date -f '-yyyy-MM-dd')
$audit_folder_path = Join-Path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')) $audit_folder_name
if (-not (Test-Path -PathType Container -Path $audit_folder_path)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $audit_folder_path -Force | Out-Null
}
```

btw - don't use variables inside single quotes, only double quotes (so they'll evaluate)